# Rest-Assured Microsoft login before api call

Tags: rest, api, office365api, rest-assured

I have secured API which uses Microsoft login before calling methods.
when I try Rest-Assured with out login

```
RestAssured.baseURI = url;
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
    Response response = httpRequest.get();

    // Retrieve the body of the Response
    ResponseBody body = response.getBody();

    // By using the ResponseBody.asString() method, we can convert the  body
    // into the string representation.
    System.out.println("Response Body is: " + body.asString());
```

I am getting below response

Response Body is:

```
<title>Sign in to your account</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedSignIn" />
<meta name="SiteID" content="" />
<meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
<meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />
<noscript>
```

how do i send microsoft login details and then use session for other api calls

Comment: I don't understand your question, Can you describe your problem in detail?

Comment: @testerBDD Please provide the call which provides the session in the response or at least let us know the details of what you are trying to achieve to debug.